# keeping track of key and values in dictionary

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dictionary `d = {'Monday': {1: [2], 5: [6], 8: [9]}, 'Tuesday': {4: [11, 12], 7: [13,15]}} and I want to return 'Tuesday' because each key within Tuesday has more values than there are within 'Monday'. This is my approach. Can someone please help? Thanks.

```
def total(d):
    name = ''
    count = 0
    for day in d:
        for num in d[day]:
            count = len(d[day][num])
            name = day
    return name
```

Comment: What do you mean "most total values"? What is the format/type of the key and value entries in your dictionary?

Comment: A dictionary is a structure that is optimized for key to value lookup. If you are looking for a key by a value (the other way around) then it might not be the best structure for your purpose.

Comment: Doing two easy things in a row doesn't make it hard, unless you let it. Maybe it would be easier for you if you write a helper function to get the score for any particular day.

Comment: What if you have `{'Monday': {1: [1,2], 2:[3]}, 'Tuesday': {1:[4], 2:[5,6]}}`? `d['Monday'][1]` is longer than `d['Tuesday'][1]`, but `d['Tuesday'][2]` is longer than `d['Monday'][2]`.

Comment: @Barmar I think when the OP says "I want to return the day with the most total values" he/she means the day with the greatest total number of items in the sub-lists. The keys to those sub-lists don't matter, as they do not match at all in the given example.

Comment: @blhsing Right, the keys don't match, but they said "each key has more values", and their attempted code just gets the length of one element at a time rather than totaling them.

Comment: The question is confusing. First you say "most total values", which sounds like you should add up the lengths of all the lists in each day. But then you say "each key has more values", which just refers to the length of each list by itself. My answer is for the second interpretation, the other answer is for the first. Please rewrite the question to make it clear.

Comment: The way you've written it suggests that all lists on each day will be the same length. Is that the case, or just a coincidence in your example (all Monday are length 1, all Tuesday are length 2)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a variable that holds the highest count found so far, and update that when the current count is higher. You should also only update `name` when that happens.

```
def total(d):
    name = ''
    maxcount = 0
    for day in d:
        for num in d[day]:
            count = len(d[day][num])
            if count > maxcount:
                maxcount = count
                name = day
    return name
```

If two days both have items with the longest length, this will return the first day.

Comment: Oh I see. Makes sense. Thank you:)

Comment: This answer returns `Tuesday` given `d = {'Monday': {1: [2], 5: [6], 8: [9]}, 'Tuesday': {7: [13,15]}}`. In my understanding, the OP would want `Monday` in this case, since it has the most total number of items in the sub-lists. Or perhaps the OP really just wants the day with the most items in *any* sub-list, which is what your implementation is about.

Comment: That's how I interpreted "each key within Tuesday has more values than there are within 'Monday'"

Comment: @Barmar I agree that statement is quite unclear, given the high probably of some sub-lists in a key having more items than some sub-lists in another key, while other sub-lists in the key having less items than the others.

Comment: @blhsing  It should return Tuesday because in 'Tuesday', 7 has 2 elements in the sublist whereas in 'Monday', each of them have only one element in the sublists.

Comment: @Barmar ^^ I hope that makes sense

Comment: @user10634718 Yes, but what about `{'Monday': {1: [1,2,3], 2:[3], 3: [4]}, 'Tuesday': {1:[4], 2:[5,6]}}`? Some lists in `Monday` are longer, and some lists in `Tuesday` are longer. With the way you describe it it would appear that you want the day with *all* keys having the longest sub-lists, which in many cases may not exist.

Comment: @blhsing So in that case, it should return 'Monday' because the longest number of items within a sublist occurs in 'Monday'.

Comment: @user10634718 I see. It's clear to me now then.

Comment: @blhsing So sorry for the confusion

Comment: @user10634718 No problem. I've updated my answer now with the new understanding.

Comment: @blhsing Yeah I read it again and I completely understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `max` function with a generator expression that returns the maximum length of the sub-lists of each sub-dicts and puts the key as the second item of a tuple for output:

```
max((max(map(len, v.values())), k) for k, v in d.items())[1]
```

This returns: `Tuesday`

Comment: So what does sum(map(len, v.values())) do?

Comment: @user10634718 analyze it bit by bit. What does `v.values()` return? What does `map(len, that)` return? And then what does `sum(that)` return?

Comment: `map(len, v.values())` would iterate through each item of `v.values()` (where each item is a list), pass the item to the `len` function for the length of each list. Then the `sum` function would take the sequence that `map` generates (lengths of the lists) and return the sum of them.

Comment: @blhsing got it, thank you.